# Ingress NGINX: Restrict access to some of my API

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Ingress NGINX: Restrict access to some of my API
Hello guys,

I’m learning microservices architectures. I use Docker and Kubernetes.

I’ve already created some services and I’m able to expose them to the world through an Ingress.

I've created two front-ends. One with Nextjs for my users reachable through domain.com and another one in pure React for managing my application reachable through manage.xxx.com.

Now, I'm a bit lost. What I want is to restrict access to some of my API. For example, I have a user service that allows my user to register and sign in through my application.

Example of requests they can perform on domain.com.

```
- POST /api/users/signup

- POST /api/users/signin
```

Example of requests that lambda user can't perform on domain.com, but can be reachable through manage.domain.com for admins.

```
- Get /api/users/all
```

how can I architecture that? Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In `Nginx` you can restrict access using specific IP or restrict access to specific folder.

Nginx can allow access using `username` and `password` with `HTTP Basic Authentication` protocol. To do it, you must use [auth_basic](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic).

> Enables validation of user name and password using the `HTTP Basic Authentication` protocol. The specified parameter is used as a realm. Parameter value can contain variables (1.3.10, 1.2.7). The special value off cancels the effect of the auth_basic directive inherited from the previous configuration level.

Nginx example configuration below:

```
location / {
    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
}
```

And specify details in `auth_basic_user_file`. The file would looks like in docs example:

Specifies a file that keeps user names and passwords, in the following format:

```
# comment
name1:password1
name2:password2:comment
name3:password3
```

Also you can mix this restrictions with others like `Basic Authentication with Access Restriction by IP Address`.

> HTTP basic authentication can be effectively combined with access restriction by IP address. You can implement at least two scenarios:
>
> - a user must be both authenticated and have a valid IP address
> - a user must be either authenticated, or have a valid IP address

Both examples can be found in [Nginx documentation example](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/#combining-basic-authentication-with-access-restriction-by-ip-address).

Other wasy to limit access is:

- [Module ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html)

> The `ngx_http_access_module` module allows limiting access to certain client addresses.

- [Module ngx_http_auth_request_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html)

> The `ngx_http_auth_request_module` module (1.5.4+) implements client authorization based on the result of a subrequest. If the subrequest returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed. If it returns 401 or 403, the access is denied with the corresponding error code. Any other response code returned by the subrequest is considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using **server snippet** configuration of Nginx ingress controller.

Add the below annotation to your ingress resource

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/service1/api/v1/data" {
          deny all;
          return 403;
        }
```

I have now control over this api **/service1/api/v1/data**, when a request comes to this api from ingress it will return **403**.